# Schwarz Lemma application problem

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions, automorphism-group

Schwarz lemma says that "Let ${\displaystyle \mathbf {D} =\{z:|z|<1\}}$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane ${\displaystyle \mathbb {C} }$  centered at the origin, and let ${\displaystyle f:\mathbf {D} \rightarrow \mathbb {C} }$ be a holomorphic map such that ${\displaystyle f(0)=0}$ and ${\displaystyle |f(z)|\leq 1}$ on ${\displaystyle \mathbf {D} }$. Then ${\displaystyle |f(z)|\leq |z|}$ for all ${\displaystyle z\in \mathbf {D} }$, and ${\displaystyle |f'(0)|\leq 1}$. Moreover, if ${\displaystyle |f(z)|=|z|}$ for some non-zero ${\displaystyle z}$ or ${\displaystyle |f'(0)|=1}$, then ${\displaystyle f(z)=az}$ for some ${\displaystyle a\in \mathbb {C} }$ with ${\displaystyle |a|=1}$."

I am trying to use this to find an analytic function $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(1/8)=4/7$ and $f(4/5)=3/7$? Could someone please explain? Thanks!

Comment: How could  you possibly use the Schwarz lemma to _find_ a function with certain properties? the lemma doesn't say anything exists...

Comment: As far as I know it does (last sentence of the first paragraph), may be I have misunderstood what you are saying ? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Ok, it's not true to say it doesn't show anything exists. It doesn't assert the existence of any holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply the Schwarz lemma directly because $f(0) = 0$ is not given.

But you can use its variant, the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem):
$$
\left|{\frac  {f(z_{1})-f(z_{2})}{1-\overline {f(z_{1})}f(z_{2})}}\right|\leq \left|{\frac  {z_{1}-z_{2}}{1-\overline {z_{1}}z_{2}}}\right|
$$
to show that such a function does not exist.

Comment: Great. Now how do we prove such a function _does_ exist?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your comment. I am thinking of constructing a map $g: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ that fixes the origin and then use Schwarz lemma. But I don't know how to construct $g$. Any idea?

Comment: @GeetThakur: $g = T_1 \circ f \circ T_2$ where $T_1, T_2$ are suitable automorphisms of the unit disk.

Comment: @MartinR Could you please explain these automorphism maps? I mean how do I defiine these and what is g here? Thanks!